# How does dapptools know which account to use from ethsign?

Tags: dapptools, ethsign, seth

I currently have 2 accounts in `ethsign`

```
$ ethsign ls
0x3DF02ac6fEe39B79654AA81C6573732439e73A81 keystore
0x643315C9Be056cDEA171F4e7b2222a4ddaB9F88D keystore
```

However, when I go to `dapp create` it always chooses the 2nd one. How does `dapp` know which account I want it to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.dapprc` it will look at your `ETH_FROM` variable, and figure out the private key to use in your `ethsign` from that.